# chosen jquery not working for values fetched from database

Tags: html, ajax, perl, cgi, jquery-chosen

I have been trying to add the chosen jquery for my selectbox which is fetching the values from database based on another. The normal selectbox works fine and all the options are getting displayed but the chosen jquery is not working.
I won't put the script tags over here because the chosen jquery is working fine for hard coded values of host names.I have applied jquery for 'host_name' scrolling list.

This is what i tried

```
$( function() {
$(".host_name").chosen();  });
```

or:

```
   $( function() {
    $("#host_name").chosen().change(host_name);  })
```

or:

```
$( function() {
    $('#host_name').trigger('chosen:updated');
})
```

perl cgi code containing ajax for fetching data from database scrolling list:

```
my $JAVASCRIPT = <<'ENDJS';
function call(host)
{
//alert("in call");
var selos=document.getElementById("ostype");
var x=selos.options[selos.selectedIndex].text;

if (x){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                var obj=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 var select = document.getElementById("host_name");
        for (var key in obj){

                                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                                        option.text = option.value = obj[key];
                                        select.add(option, 0);

                                        //document.getElementById('host_name').appendChild(var);
                                }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "logic.cgi?ostype="+x, true);

  xhttp.send();

}
}
```

cgi code for html

```
 $q->start_td({-colspan=>2}),
       $q->scrolling_list(-name=>'ostype',
-size=>1,
-id=>'ostype',
-values=>['RHEL','Windows','SLES'],
-onClick=>'together()',
-onChange=>'call()'
),
$q->end_td,



"Host name",$q->font({-color=>'red'},"*") ,
$q->end_td,
 $q->start_td({-colspan=>2}),

$q->scrolling_list({-style=>'width:150px',
-name=>'host_name',
-class=>'host_name',
-id=>'host_name',
-size=>'3',
-values=>[],
-multiple=>'true'}
),
```

Comment: What happened to your other question? Did you figure it out on your own?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function() {
$(".host_name").chosen();  });
```

The `$(".host_name")` jQuery selector selects all elements with the **class** hostname (e.g. `<div class="host_name"></div>`).

```
   $( function() {
    $("#host_name").chosen().change(host_name);  })
```

The `$("#host_name")` jQuery selector selects all elements with the **id** hostname (e.g. `<div id="host_name"></div>`)

```
$( function() {
    $('#host_name').trigger('chosen:updated');
})
```

You might want to check the [chosen() documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for usage examples, too.

There's an error in your commented-out bit of JavaScript:

```
//document.getElementById('host_name').appendChild(var);
```

It should be

```
//document.getElementById('host_name').appendChild(option);
```

Comment: i changed the class to 'hosts' and it's still not working.. please tell me what to do exactly.

Comment: but your html has an **id** not a class?

Comment: please can you post your html and your jQuery, as I can't see what the problem is from what you have posted

Comment: see it has an attribute -class=>'host_name',... i have changed it to 'hosts'

Comment: in that case, your jquery should be `$( function() {
$(".hosts").chosen();  });` (and your html should be `class="host_name"`

Comment: so u mean class name and the name that chosen() calls should be different?

Comment: oh dear, no, sorry, I mean `$( function() { $(".hosts").chosen(); });` and your html should be `class="hosts"`